# How to reindex solr after schema change?

Tags: solr

We need to modify the schema fields dynamically, which requires reindexing.The solr ref guide recommands deleting all the documents and then re-run the original index process,but that does fit us.Does anyone have other ideas?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Reindexing is required. Best option is using Data Import Handler. If you don't want to run the queries from database or don't want to pass documents, then also **solr provides way to index the solr core through other solr core**.
You can do something like this :

For more details, read solr DIH and **SolrEntityProcessor** : https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#solrentityprocessor